# How to get News previous and next news in contao ?

Tags: contao

**How to i get News previous and next news in contao ? 
  f.e 
  < Previous News  |  Current news ( id - 4) | Next News >
  I want Previous and next news link in detail page..**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following extension: [[newspagination](https://contao.org/en/extension-list/view/newspagination.en.html)]

In case you are not using the default `mod_newsreader` template, you need to add the following line:

```
<?php echo $this->addNewsPagination() ?>
```

or just

```
<?= $this->addNewsPagination() ?>
```

with PHP `5.4+`